# How to install browser on Bluemix Pipeline Test Stage?

Tags: ubuntu, ibm-cloud

I have a Node 8, Angular 6 application that I will be deploying with the Bluemix Pipeline. In the pipeline, I have set up Mocha tests for the back end and the front end. I now want to write e2e tests, but I can't figure out how to install a browser on the test stage, which runs Ubuntu 14. The closest I got was:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome- 
stable_current_amd64.deb
ar -x ./google-chrome*.deb
tar xf data.tar.xz
export CHROME_BIN=usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
```

But I got the following error:

```
15 06 2018 16:56:41.566:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
15 06 2018 16:56:43.569:WARN [launcher]: Chrome was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
15 06 2018 16:56:45.572:WARN [launcher]: Chrome was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.
```